# $\cos x+i\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ix)^n}{n!}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Please, help-me to show that $\cos x+i\sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ix)^n}{n!}$.

$\cos x+i \sin x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$. How should I proceed from now on?

Comment: is taylor expansion of sine and cosine allowed?

Comment: It might be slightly easier to see by expanding and separating $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ix)^n}{n!}$ into real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Note that $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, then use Taylor series for exponential function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, 
$$\cos(x)=1+\frac{-x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}...$$
$$i\sin(x)=ix+\frac{-ix^3}{3!}+\frac{ix^5}{5!}...$$
$$\cos(x)+i\sin(x)=1+ix+\frac{-x^2}{2!}+\frac{-ix^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{ix^5}{5!}...$$
Now see a propery of $i$,
$$i^0=1$$
$$i^1=i$$
$$i^2=-1$$
$$i^3=-i$$
$$i^4=1$$
$$i^5=i$$
and so on in cycles of four, now, looking at the original problem, we may want to rewrite it as:
$$\cos(x)+i\sin(x)=i^01+i^1x+\frac{i^2x^2}{2!}+\frac{i^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{i^4x^4}{4!}+\frac{i^5x^5}{5!}...$$
Thus the identity becomes apparent.